# Delete standard icon in windows form

Tags: winforms, icons

how to just delete that windows form application icon in the left corner without replacing it with another icon?

Comment: What programming language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I assume that you're using .Net WinForms.

Set the form's [ShowIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showicon.aspx) property to `false`.

Answer (score 8):

If it is .NET (Winforms) the form should have a ShowIcon property. Set this to false.

Answer (score 1):

in case you're using C++

```
HWND hWnd;  // = WindowHandle()
::SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE, 
                ::GetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) | WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME);
```